# Certain Electrical things not working on Dodge Stratus

Tags: dodge, locks, power-windows, cruise-control, stratus

I have a 2002 Dodge Stratus SE Plus.  2.7L.  Certain things on it are not quite working.  They are:

1. Air Bag light is on
2. Horn doesn't work
3. Cruise control doesn't turn on at all
4. Passenger side windows will not work but Driver side does.
5. Dome light flickers when I turn it on
6. Back passenger "backup light" is out
7. Power locks do not work

Is there a chance some or all of these are linked together?  If so, how?  What do I do to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! For the most part, these issues seem disparate and not associated. I'd go one by one and fix the issues, such as the horn is very easy to test by just applying a 12v power source to it. If it works, it's most likely the relay. Also, have you had the codes for the air bags since the light is on? This can tell you a lot about what may be wrong with that system and leave the guessing behind.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 horn, airbag light and cruise control may be linked via the clock spring.